# Does the origin check need to be hardcoded when receiving a message?

Tags: javascript, postmessage

We are always told to check the origin of an incoming message before trusting/processing it as any domain can send a message to any other domain.  This I get, but do I have to compare the origin with a hardcoded string or could I simply extract the domain that my code is currently running on?

For example, this is what the examples say you must do:

```
function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://YOURDOMAIN.org")
    return;
  // ..process message..
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

But could I not use this equally?

```
// Determine origin from url (once only)
const origin = (function (w) {
    var arr = w.location.href.split("/");
    return arr[0] + "//" + arr[2];
})(window);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== origin)
    return;
  // ..process message..
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

The reason I ask is that my code could be running on any of a few test/staging and demo environments, not just our production environment and each environment is on a separate domain. Thanks.

Comment: The main purpose of postMessage is to allow _cross-origin_ communication - so unless have a case where you are using it to communicate within the _same_ origin, I don't see how extracting the domain under which this receiving code is running, could help?

Comment: And if you are using it same origin then just getting rid of it would likely simplify your code a lot.